# Unity A* Pathfiding from a list

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I'm developing a Dungeon Crawler style game and set a bunch of position objects as a "grid" for the player walk and stored them in a parent object, like a list. So I wanted to use that same list for the enemy moviment but after watching many A* Pathfinding tutorials for weeks I didn't managed to have any ideas of how to solve it since I'm not using a regular 2D grid. Here's a [reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaqSZ.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your image, and you do in-fact have a grid.  Just because you placed your objects does not mean you can calculate the "grid" for them from the list.

I would suggest you create a function that you call when your level starts.. and it iterates through the children of that object and generates a data structure that allows you to use A* to calculate pathing.  You can use the transform.position of each object to determine it's relative placement/adjacency.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Got it. But does this data structure mean a node or just the G cost? I had already thought about iterating each position and giving them an X and Y value but I didn't know how, maybe based on the distance between them which is 3x3?

Comment: Lookup quad tree construction, that should get you going.  You can actually find quad tree A* path finding examples as well.  Your quad tree will actually wind up being a grid because all of your objects are of equal size and shape, with the same distance between adjacent nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways you can do this. One suggestion would be creating an invisible collider with a trigger (can be on an empty GameObject) in different areas on your grid. Give the enemy a default velocity and attach a collider to the enemy and select the checkbox for trigger so when the enemy moves onto the trigger, you can call OnTriggerEnter (from a script attached to the enemy or the invisible collider GameObject) and make it change its movement. How you want to implement the AI is up to you.

edit as per comment

put invisible game objects positioned in your scene to how you would envision them being in an array from a birds eye view. In a script assign them to an array. Get the enemy to lerp between points in the array based on your ai algorithm. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought implementing the AI in a way that it could walk by an array of pre determined positions from some A* calculation using the "Path" list from the image.